# Cannot create file on /tmp but can create directory

Tags: linux, permissions

Am having a strange issue in my linux box on the /tmp directory

I can create a directory and touch a file in this but not in /tmp directly:

```
/tmp]# touch a.txt
touch: setting times of `a.txt': No such file or directory
/tmp]# touch b.txt
touch: setting times of `b.txt': No such file or directory


/tmp]# mkdir toto
/tmp]# touch toto/a.txt
```

Here are the permissions of /tmp

```
drwxrwxrwx.    9 root root  4096 Sep  7 08:43 tmp

ls -Z |grep tmp
drwxrwxrwt  root root ?                                tmp
```

There is the strace of the touch commmand:

```
/tmp]# strace touch /tmp/a.txt
execve("/bin/touch", ["touch", "/tmp/a.txt"], [/* 38 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd1a000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f971d778000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36757, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 36757, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f971d76f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=43944, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128816, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f971d352000
mprotect(0x7f971d359000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f971d558000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f971d558000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\356\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1920936, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3750152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f971cfbe000
mprotect(0x7f971d148000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f971d348000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18a000) = 0x7f971d348000
mmap(0x7f971d34d000, 18696, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f971d34d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000^\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=142688, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f971d76e000
mmap(NULL, 2212848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f971cda1000
mprotect(0x7f971cdb8000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f971cfb8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f971cfb8000
mmap(0x7f971cfba000, 13296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f971cfba000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f971d76d000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f971d76c000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f971d76d700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f971cfb8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f971d348000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f971d558000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f971d779000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f971d76f000, 36757)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f971d76d9d0)         = 5330
set_robust_list(0x7f971d76d9e0, 24)     = 0
futex(0x7fff99010c8c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7fff99010c8c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7f971d76d700) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f971cda6cb0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f971cdb07e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f971cda6d40, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f971cdb07e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd1a000
brk(0xd3b000)                           = 0xd3b000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99158576, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99158576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9716f10000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/tmp/a.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
utimensat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/a.txt", NULL, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2512, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f971d777000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2512
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f971d777000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=435, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 435, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f971d777000
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "touch: ", 7touch: )                  = 7
write(2, "setting times of `/tmp/a.txt'", 29setting times of `/tmp/a.txt') = 29
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": No such file or directory", 27: No such file or directory) = 27
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

What is preventing me from touching a file directly in /tmp ?

For info am using user root.

**UPDATE:**

```
getfacl /tmp
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tmp
# owner: root
# group: root
# flags: --t
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

Comment: what is output of `sudo du -hs /tmp`

Comment: @Rahul `76K     /tmp` thx

Comment: @user4556274  PLease check update

Comment: Is it only ```touch``` which does not work? What about ```echo > /tmp/a.txt```? Does ```mktemp``` work and which path does it use?

Comment: @rudimeier No even mktemp is not working `mktemp: failed to create file via template `b.txt.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX': Invalid argument`

Comment: Might be selinux, what does `getenforce` say?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz SELINUX is disabled

Comment: Have you tried ```mktemp``` without argument? I wanted to see which TMPDIR is used by default. My guess was that your distro wants to force you to use private tempdirs. What kind of distro you are using by the way?

Comment: Is the filesystem ok? Did you check with `fsck`? What filesystem is it?

Comment: @MartinSugioarto Yes the FS is ok and `fsck` commands shows nothing anormal. I dont think its related to FS since am able to create directories and files in the directories created. For info its `ext3`

Comment: I think you have a rootkit. Check your binary files and kernelmodules and ld_preload values.

Comment: What filesystem is `/tmp`? Post the output of `grep /tmp /proc/mounts`. What distribution is this? Is this a virtualized system (e.g. openvz, docker container, …)?

Answer (score -2):

> Caution:  This suggested solution might not be a bad idea but could have negative impacts on currently running programs.  Use at your own risk.

Try as root :

```
chattr -R -iau /tmp
rm -rf /tmp
mkdir /tmp
chmod 777 /tmp
```

and try again if all is fine after this

Comment: Seems like a drastic "solution" to me!

Comment: While it is extreme, it could possibly be the basis of a functional solution.  For that reason I'd leave it open with a warning.

Comment: ```chmod 777 /tmp``` without sticky bit is wrong